# How to fix AOT ExecutionEngineException for GenericEqualityComparer of struct in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm making a Unity game on iOS. I'm aware of the AOT limitations. When I added a Dictionary which happened to have a struct Key type, I got a flurry of ExecutionEngineExceptions. Most of these I could fix by dummy-declaring things, to make it visible to the AOT compiler:

```
Dictionary<MyStruct,GameObject> dummy;
```

However the last remaining error is for `GenericEqualityComparer<MyStruct>`. I can't dummy-declare this, as it's not public in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

I tried `var dummy = EqualityComparer<MyStruct>.Default` but that didn't work.

I tried making my own comparer, `class StructComparer : EqualityComparer<MyStruct>` and using that in the dictionary constructor, but I get the same error except now from within the StructComparer constructor callstack.

I really don't want to convert this struct into a class. Is there a way to get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this [Value types as Dictionary Keys limitations](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#Value_types_as_Dictionary_Keys) workaround should be what you need:

"Manually implement the IEqualityComparer interface in a new type and provide an instance of that type to the Dictionary (IEqualityComparer) constructor."

I.e., you'll need a class that implements IEqualityComparer, then pass an instance of it to the Dictionary constructor.

What's lovely is that it would appear [someone made a patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mono-svn-patches/t9ELLW_WSfE/AWq5Y43uhaoJ) (not sure if it was merged) to fix this AOT bug in Mono 2.8+. However, that doesn't help Unity users since the devs are still using 2.6.5 I believe.